# Amp-carousel stops autoplaying function is very random - AMPHTML Ads

Tags: html, css, amp-html

Amp-carousel's autoplay seems to be working randomly and functionality relies heavily on other elements on the page.

The autoplay will sometimes play only one cycle, but then if you add a simple empty line in the code, random place. I guess the cache clears and the carousel is autoplaying indefinitely again.

Another case, if the carousel has other siblings above, the autoplay stops working.

See below an example with two amp-carousel elements. The one at top works, but soon as you add spacing between the parent the amp-carousel, it stops autoplaying.

The second one, doesn't work at all, if you comment out the siblings above it, the autoplay works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4ads>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700">  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp4ads-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
  <style amp-custom>

        * {
          /* box-sizing: border-box; */
          border: 1px solid red;
        }

         body {
          font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }

        .banner {
          height: 600px;
          width: 100%;
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
          color: #fff;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .banner::after {
         content: '';
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.87) 98%);
         z-index: 1;
       }

        .bannner__img {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }

        .banner__container {
          position: relative;
          z-index: 3;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;

        }

        .banner__features {
         padding:0;
         margin-bottom: auto;
         /* margin-top: 13rem; */
        }

        .banner__heading {
        }

        .banner__subheading {

        }

        .text-slider {
          width: 100%;
          border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .cover img {
          object-fit: cover;
        }
       .slider-container {
         position: relative;
       }

       a.cta {
         position: absolute;
         font-size: 12px;
         font-weight: 300;
         letter-spacing: 3px;
         bottom: 1rem;
         left: 50%;
         transform: translateX(-50%);
         border: 1px solid #fff;
         background: #EC2623;
         padding: 1.25rem 1.25rem;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         text-decoration: none;
         color: white;
         z-index: 2;
         display: inline-block;
       }
       .amp-carousel-slide {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .amp-carousel-slide[aria-hidden=false] {
        transition: opacity 1s;
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .amp-carousel-button {
        visibility: collapse;
        /* display: none; */
      } 
      </style>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/amp4ads-v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- <div style="height:20rem;"></div>  -->

<amp-carousel class="text-slider" height="50" layout="fixed-height" type="slides" autoplay delay="300">
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 1</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 2</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 3</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 4</p>
  </amp-carousel>

<div class="banner">
  <amp-carousel class="text-slider" height="50" layout="fixed-height" type="slides" autoplay delay="300">
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 1</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 2</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 3</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 4</p>
    </amp-carousel>
  <amp-img class="cover banner__img" layout="fill" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000"></amp-img>
  <div class="banner__container">


   <h1 class="banner__heading">Heading ipsum lorem lorem</h1>
    <h3 class="banner__subheading">Subheading lorem</h3>

    <div class="banner__features">
      <amp-carousel class="text-slider" height="50" layout="fixed-height" type="slides" autoplay delay="300">
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 1</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 2</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 3</p>
        <p class="banner__features-title">Slide 4</p>
    </amp-carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="cta">Get in Touch</a>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZBBwZ?editors=1000#0)